# How can one make hyperref work together with sort&compress option of natbib?

Tags: hyperref, natbib

I am trying to compile a manuscript using `elsearticle` template. I have had a hard time making `hyperref` work together with `natbib`. I know it should be loaded as the last package, but it still causes some issues like de-compressing the multiple citations in my text. So in the end, the only solution remained was to remove it. Just FYI, my document contains a lot of packages and I really don't know if `hyperref` is possibly incompatible with any of those packages (is there a list of packages like that?). Does anyone have any clue what may cause `hyperref` not go along well with `natbib` and its options?

Comment: so you have an unknown problem with an unknown combinations of packages. Do you really expect us to be able to tell you what is going on? elsarticle already loads natbib, but not with sort&compress, so it is quite impossible to guess what you are actually doing.

Comment: Actually the problem is not unknown.  sort&compress doesn't work with hyperref as I have clearly explained: "it causes decompressing of citations". I am just asking if a certain combination of packages I am using could be a problem. If not, does anyone have any clue what could be the issue?

Comment: Well I'm one of the hyperref maintainer and I have no idea what you mean. Show a complete example.

Comment: ok let me put it this way:
when I use `natbib` with the following options: `[numbers, sort&compress]` I get my multiple citations in the text like [1, 8-12]. But, when I put `hyperref` "as the last package" to get my references, figure and table citations hyperlinked, it converts my multiple references to [1, 8, 9 , 10, 11, 12].

Comment: Edit your question and add an small but complete example demonstrating your problem.

Comment: If you want any more help you really **must** show us a short example document (that is fully compilable, contains a `\documentclass` line and `\begin{document}...\end{document}` etc. etc., see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that shows us what you are doing. I can't even load `natbib` with the option `[numbers, sort&compress]` with the `elsearticle` class, since that produces an option clash.

Comment: For some reason it mal-functions on my laptop. On overleaf it works. Thanks anyways!